# Cannot Write and Read Saved Game Files

Tags: java, buffer

I am having issues writing data from my game to a file and loading it so I can resume the game from the state that it was in when I saved it's data. I have gotten thus far but it consistently throws a null pointer exception. When I click on saveGame I use a buffered writer to write the string value of all my data. I then load the file by reading from the file, I am not sure how to actually display the read data but before I try to get that far I need to fix the null pointer exception throw from happening.
I have tried writing to the file which I'm pretty confident in the path being correct so I'm not sure as to why it's doing this.

***Code***

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.image.*;

public class LifeApplication extends JFrame implements Runnable, MouseListener, MouseMotionListener {

    private BufferStrategy strategy;
    private Graphics offscreenBuffer;
    private boolean gameState[][][]= new boolean[40][40][2];
    private int gameStateFrontBuffer = 0;
    private boolean isGameRunning = false;
    private boolean initialised;
    private static LoadSave loadSave;

    public LifeApplication()
    {
        Dimension screensize = java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        int x = screensize.width/2 - 400;
        int y = screensize.height/2 - 400;
        setBounds(x,y,800,800);
        setVisible(true);
        this.setTitle("Conway's Game of Life");

        createBufferStrategy(2);
        strategy = getBufferStrategy();
        offscreenBuffer = strategy.getDrawGraphics();

        addMouseListener(this);
        addMouseMotionListener(this);

        for(x = 0; x < 40; x++)
        {
            for(y = 0; y < 40; y++)
            {
                gameState[x][y][0] = gameState[x][y][1] = false;
            }
        }

        Thread t = new Thread(this);
        t.start();

        initialised = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        while(true)
        {
            try{Thread.sleep(100);}
            catch(InterruptedException e){
                System.out.println("Something happened but dont worry");
            }

            if(isGameRunning)
                applyRules();

            this.repaint();
        }
    }

    private void applyRules()
    {
        int front = gameStateFrontBuffer;
        int back = (front +1)%2;

        for(int x = 0; x < 40; x++)
        {
            for(int y = 0; y < 40; y++)
            {
                int liveneighbours = 0;
                for(int xx = -1; xx <= 1; xx++)
                {
                    for(int yy = -1; yy <= 1; yy++)
                    {
                        if(xx!=0 || yy!=0)
                        {
                            int xxx = x+xx;
                            if(xxx < 0)
                                xxx=39;
                            else if(xxx > 39)
                                xxx = 0;
                            int yyy = y + yy;
                            if(yyy < 0)
                                yyy=39;
                            else if (yyy>39)
                                yyy=0;
                            if(gameState[xxx][yyy][front])
                                liveneighbours++;
                        }
                    }
                }

                if(gameState[x][y][front])
                {
                    if(liveneighbours < 2)
                        gameState[x][y][back] =false;
                    else if(liveneighbours < 4)
                        gameState[x][y][back] =true;
                    else
                        gameState[x][y][back] =false;
                }
                else
                {
                    if(liveneighbours == 3)
                        gameState[x][y][back] =true;
                    else
                        gameState[x][y][back] =false;
                }
            }
        }
        gameStateFrontBuffer = back;
    }

    private void randomiseGameState()
    {
        for(int x = 0; x < 40; x++)
        {
            for(int y = 0; y < 40; y++)
            {
                gameState[x][y][gameStateFrontBuffer] = (Math.random()< 0.25);
            }
        }
    }

        @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent m)
    {

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent m)
    {

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent m)
    {

    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent m)
    {
        if(!isGameRunning)
        {
            int x = m.getX();
            int y = m.getY();
            if(x >= 15 && x <= 85 && y >= 40 && y <= 70) {
                isGameRunning = true;
                return;
            }

            if(x >= 115 && x <= 215 && y >= 40 && y <= 70) {
                randomiseGameState();
                return;
            }

            if(x >= 245 && x <= 315 && y >= 40 && y <= 70){
                loadSave.saveGame();
            }
            if(x >= 345 && x <= 415 && y >= 40 && y <= 70){
                loadSave.loadGame();
                isGameRunning = true;
            }
        }

        int x = m.getX()/20;
        int y = m.getY()/20;

        gameState[x][y][gameStateFrontBuffer] = !gameState[x][y][gameStateFrontBuffer];

        this.repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent m)
    {

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
        if(!isGameRunning) {
            int x = mouseEvent.getX();
            int y = mouseEvent.getY();
            try {
                if (gameState[x / 20][y / 20][gameStateFrontBuffer]) {
                    gameState[x / 20][y / 20][gameStateFrontBuffer] = !gameState[x / 20][y / 20][gameStateFrontBuffer];
                }
                if (!gameState[x / 20][y / 20][gameStateFrontBuffer]) {
                    gameState[x / 20][y / 20][gameStateFrontBuffer] = true;
                }
            }
            catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e){
                System.out.println("Cant go there thats out of bounds");
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {

    }

    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        if(!initialised)
            return;

        g = offscreenBuffer;

        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, 800, 800);

        g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        g.fillRect(245, 40, 70, 30);
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.drawString("Save", 252, 62);

        g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        g.fillRect(345, 40, 70, 30);
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.drawString("Load", 352, 62);


        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        for(int x = 0; x < 40; x++)
        {
            for(int y = 0; y < 40; y++)
            {
                if(gameState[x][y][gameStateFrontBuffer])
                    g.fillRect(x*20, y*20, 20, 20);
            }
        }

        if(!isGameRunning)
        {
            g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
            g.fillRect(15, 40, 70, 30);
            g.fillRect(115, 40, 100, 30);
            g.setFont(new Font("Times", Font.PLAIN, 24));
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g.drawString("Start", 22, 62);
            g.drawString("Random", 122, 62);
        }
        strategy.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LifeApplication lifeApp = new LifeApplication();
    }

}
```

```
import java.io.*;

public class LoadSave {
    LifeApplication lifeApplication;

    public void saveGame() {

        String filename = "C:\\Users\\brads\\Desktop\\GameOfLife.txt";
        try {
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(filename));

            writer.write(String.valueOf(lifeApplication));
            writer.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Cannot write to file");
        }
    }

    public void loadGame() {
        String line = null;
        String filename = "saveFile.txt";
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
            do {
                try {
                    line = reader.readLine();

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    System.out.println("Cannot read from text file");
                }
            }
            while (line != null);
            reader.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you provide the stack trace of the exception you're getting?

Comment: Where exactly are you getting the NullPointerException?

Comment: Not sure if it's related to the problem you're having, but you are calling `String.valueOf` on your LifeApplication object. But since your LifeApplication class does not override it's `toString()` method, the string you will be getting will most likely not contain the data you want it to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don’t think you’re creating the `LoadSave` instance.

Try adding something like:

```
public LifeApplication()
{
    ...

    loadSave = new LoadSave();
    loadSave.lifeAaplication = this;

    ....
}
```